# Workaround needed for the incomplete implementation of window functions in Google Big Query (GBQ)

Tags: google-bigquery

The recently announced (and long-awaited) window analytical functions in Google Big Query seems very incomplete. Below is a query that was supposed to calculate the combined weighted score of several (3 in the example) financial indicators of a company (this works in Oracle and MS SQL!):

```
select 
  (  percent_rank() over (order by cash_discount desc)*0.4
    +percent_rank() over (order by trailing_pe desc)*0.5
    +percent_rank() over (order by forward_pe desc)*0.5
  ) combined_weighted_score
 ,company_symbol, company_name
 from  workspace.company c
```

In GBQ we get: **Error: Encountered " "OVER" "over "" at line 2.**

I decided to research the issue further - here is an even simpler query:

```
select 
      percent_rank() over (order by cash_discount desc) r1
     ,percent_rank() over (order by trailing_pe desc) r2
     ,percent_rank() over (order by forward_pe desc) r3
     ,company_symbol, company_name
from  workspace.company c
```

which gets me this: **Error: Multiple distinct OVER clauses are not yet supported. If more than one OVER clauses appear in a query they must be identical. Found AnalyticSpecs that differ in sort keys 0**

So, GBQ appears to have very incomplete implementation of analytical window functions! 
Next, I tried some ugly hacks like:

```
select c.company_name, (r1.r*0.4+r2.r*0.5) combined_weighted_score
from [workspace.company] c
left join (select company_symbol, percent_rank() over (order by cash_discount desc) r from workspace.company) r1 
  on c.company_symbol=r1.company_symbol
left join (select company_symbol, percent_rank() over (order by trailing_pe desc) r from workspace.company) r2 
  on c.company_symbol=r2.company_symbol
```

well, still does not work:

**Error: 5.1 - 0.0: A query cannot have multiple JOIN clauses**

**Any solutions**? I know this is very hard to implement in classic SQL, without the help of properly implemented window functions. But GBQ annoucement sounded very promissing ...

Answer (score 2):

You almost got it!

Every OVER() clause needs the same predicate in the same SELECT statement, but you can JOIN 2 different tables - as you found out.

Only 2 tables can be joined, but you need 3. The easy workaround is to do a subquery and JOIN that one.

Instead of:

```
SELECT x.a, y.b, z.c
FROM x JOIN y ON x.j=y.j JOIN z ON y.j=z.j
```

you can do:

```
SELECT x.a, yz.b, yz.c
FROM x JOIN (
  SELECT y.b b, z.c c, y.j j
  FROM y JOIN z on y.j=z.j) yz
ON x.j=yz.j
```

(you might need to change the JOIN for a JOIN EACH)

Comment: Thanks Fh.! The workaround works, but such unnecessary nested JOINs won't win any beauty contest:-).I still hope the GBQ team monitors their clients' pain and for the next release will at least :
1. Remove the restrictions of having only one type of OVER clause in the same SELECT
2. Realize that expressions like 0.4*(percent_rank() over(...)) are entirely legitimateThanks Fh., The workaround works! I still hope the GBQ team monitors their client's pain and at least will do:

Comment: As far as I've experienced - the GBQ teams loves their users. Thanks for the feedback, and keep it coming :).